# Running spacyr error cant find ludwig/python.exe

Tags: r

I tried to run spacyr https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr on my computer.

I received errors:

```
Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment spacy_condaenv
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\SEBAST~1.MIO\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\ludwig/python.exe": Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\SEBAST~1.MIO\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\rStudio/python.exe": Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
```

Answer (score 0):

I go the similar error the thing spacyr will run with backend of conda environment do the

following

library("spacyr") #import the library

spacy_install() #after that install spacy using this

spacy_initialize()# then initialize it to start the spacy in your environment .

look in to the spacyr documentation for more details